# Why have I got a low ABV wine problem

Tags: first-time-brewer, primary-fermentation, stuck-fermentation, fruit-wine

This was my first attempt. I followed a recipe for jam wine in CJJ Berry's book. Did exactly what he said. Temperature between 26°C-28°C on the heat strip. Used Lalvin K1-V1116. Start OG 1.090, final FG 1.040. ie 6.5% ABV.

Added re-start yeast...no difference. What do I do now?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: For how long did you ferment?

Comment: Perhaps, post entire recipe as well.

Comment: So wine - "made from Jam" - Jam as in "Condiment made from 50% fruit, 50% sugar" ... right?  Did your jam have preservatives in it?

Comment: Sorry, next time just buy some frozen fruit and sugar and make a wine out of that. Who knows what is in the "jam"

Answer (score 1):

I started out making a blackberry-Cabernet wine, adding if I remember 6 jars of jam to 3 gallons of water, x amount of sugar to a SG of 1.090 or about 12 % ABV. I used EC1118 yeast and low and behold I ended up with stuck fermentations every time, just about the same SG as you. If I recall correctly there is something in the jam (chemical) that interferes with the fermentation process.  I added yeast nutrient, warmed the wine and coaxed it to finish. It took a couple of weeks, never went totally dry, but blended with a Cab, it was pretty good.  Next time don’t use jam, buy an Alexander product of blackberry concentrate. Much more predictable and satisfying.

Comment: Indeed, if the jam contains sulfites or sorbates it may cause problems with the fermentation.

Comment: I don’t recall what was in the jam that stalled the fermentation but, it was widely spoken about on major wine making forums.  I certainly wasn’t the first to get stuck.